# Flip card on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made blocks that when you click on them they are turning around. Well.. it works,but as always there is gonna be a but. First click is working propetly, but second one makes block  turn around very quick and then it comes back to default position. After I clicked once problem is gone. I gotta do it with every single block. here's a link, but you have to insert jquery library (it is above js code)

```js
checkClick = true;
function seeBlock(block){
            $(block).click(function(){

                if(checkClick == true)
                {    
                    $(".block.front" + block).css({"transform": "rotateY(180deg)"});
                    $(".block.back" + block).css({"transform": "rotateY(0deg)"});
                    checkClick = false;
                }
                else if(checkClick == false)
                {    
                    $(".block.front" + block).css({"transform": "rotateY(0deg)"});
                    $(".block.back" + block).css({"transform": "rotateY(180deg)"});
                    checkClick = true;
                }
            }); 
        }
        seeBlock(".block1");
        seeBlock(".block2");
        seeBlock(".block3");
        seeBlock(".block4");
        seeBlock(".block5");
        seeBlock(".block6");
```

```css
.block {
    color:#7a7a7a;
    width: 300px;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: #8ee1f4;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 24px 0px rgba(142, 225, 244, 1);
    margin: 15px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transition: all 700ms ease;

}
.block:hover {
    background-color: #65dbf5;
}
.block.back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
/* .blocks:hover .block.front{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.blocks:hover .block.back{
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
} */
.block.front.block2, .block.back.block2  {
    margin-left: 400px;
}
.block.front.block3, .block.back.block3  {
    margin-left: 800px;
}
.block.front.block4, .block.back.block4  {
    margin-top: 250px;
}
.block.front.block5, .block.back.block5  {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 400px;
}
.block.front.block6, .block.back.block6  {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 800px;
}
.back {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocks">
            <div class="block front block1">Trampoliny</div>
            <div class="block back block1">rekreacyjne, skośne, sportowe ścieżki , basen z gąbkami, air bag i jeszcze kilka niespodzianek czeka na was.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocks">
            <div class="block front block2">BAYBY GYM</div>
            <div class="block back block2">to tu odbywa się najlepsza zabawa poprzez sport dla najmłodszych. Pokonywanie miękkich przeszkód, podstawy gimnastyki wspólne wygłupy z rodzicami.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocks">
            <div class="block front block3">Klocki</div>
            <div class="block back block3">Nic tak nie rozwija jak klocki. Małe, duże i wielkie klocki ,a to nie wszystko, mamy coś jeszcze.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocks">
            <div class="block front block4">Cafe</div>
            <div class="block back block4">Podczas gdy wasze dzieci będą spędzały kolejne godziny na nieograniczonych atrakcjach wy możecie rozkoszować się wspaniałą kawą i ciastem w naszej kawiarni.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocks">
            <div class="block front block5">SALA GIMNASTYCZNA</div>
            <div class="block back block5">najlepsze miejsce do treningu wyczynowego jak i amatorskiego. Poprawa koordynacji, gibkość ,szybkość, sprawność i zdrowie .</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocks">
            <div class="block front block6">Joga</div>
            <div class="block back block6"> idealny sposób na harmonie ciała i duszy, nasza sala do jogi a na niej zajęcia również dla mam z dziećmi.</div>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been using a variable `checkClick` that is global to all your blocks, which can only make things complicated. When you click on one block, it updates its value for all the others.
You need to store the state of a block within the block itself (as a class for example).

The modification I came up with is this :

```js
function seeBlock(block){
  $(block).click(function(){

    // If block has not yet been clicked flip it
    if(! $(block).hasClass('clicked'))
    {    
      $(".block.front" + block).css({"transform": "rotateY(180deg)"});
      $(".block.back" + block).css({"transform": "rotateY(0deg)"});

      $(block).toggleClass('clicked'); // Adds the class .clicked
    }
    // Otherwise flip it back
    else
    {    
      $(".block.front" + block).css({"transform": "rotateY(0deg)"});
      $(".block.back" + block).css({"transform": "rotateY(180deg)"});

      $(block).toggleClass('clicked'); // Removes the class .clicked
    }
  }); 
}
seeBlock(".block1");
seeBlock(".block2");
seeBlock(".block3");
seeBlock(".block4");
seeBlock(".block5");
seeBlock(".block6");
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I'm gonna be careful with global variable